# editing many-to-many junction table in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

the user can select form a set list of items which ones they want to sell on their page, and can also set the price per unit for each of the items.

the Models used look something like this:
user, user_product_category, product_category

as above, i have three models, and the user_product_category model has a column called "price"

The user model looks like this:

```
has_many :user_product_category
has_many :product_category through: :user_product_category
```

the database has a "username" column.

as for the user_product_category model:

```
belongs_to :users
belongs_to :product_category
```

the database has these columns:

```
user_id, :integer
product_category_id, :integer
price, :integer
```

for the product_category model:

```
has_many :user_product_category
has_many :users through: :user_product_category
```

it has a "name" column

1. show checkboxes for all items selectable for the user using ProductCategories.all

2.create textfields next to each of the checkboxes to allow the user to set the price for each of the items that they selected

3.when you click on the update button, params are set for user_product_category controller. and the controller does these things:
creates junction tables for the checked items
deletes tables for item that HAD a check, but does not anymore
validates the price_fields

for example,
lets say we have user A with and id of user_id=1
and we have selectable items:

- item１(id=1)
- item２(id=2)
- item３(id=3)

user a first checks item1, and sets the price to $10
↓ 
in user_product_category a table is created:

```
id=1 
user_id=1 
product_categories_id=1 
price=1000
```

then user A unchecks item 1, and checks items 2 and 3. sets both of the prices to $12. clicks update

↓

in user_product_category table:
record for id=1 is deleted, and records for id=2 and id=3 are created

```
id=2 
user_id=1 
product_categories_id=2 
price=1200

id=3 
user_id=1 
product_categories_id=3 
price=1200
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make this work. how would I set the strong parameters to validate for the price fields?
Am I missing something crucial?
It would be greate if anyone could help me.